# Arduino Read Integer From Txt

Tags: java, c++, arduino, readfile, sd-card

I'm trying to read my integer txt file from sd card.

My txt has these 2 lines (first line is 1, second is \n);

```
1
```

I did a reader code like;

```
#include <SD.h>
#include <SPI.h>
File myFile;
int pinCS = 53;
void setup() {
    
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(pinCS, OUTPUT);
  
  // SD Card Initialization
  if (SD.begin())
  {
    Serial.println("SD card is ready to use.");
  } else
  {
    Serial.println("SD card initialization failed");
    return;
  }
  // Reading the file
  myFile = SD.open("test.txt", FILE_READ);
  if (myFile) {
    Serial.println("Read:");
    // Reading the whole file
    while (myFile.available()) {
      Serial.write(myFile.read());
   }
    myFile.close();
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("error opening test.txt");
  }
  
}
void loop() {
  // empty
}
```

It works but what I want is read my integer from txt file and sum with another integer (that is `int total` in my below code. I tried this but it doesn't work;

```
#include <SD.h>
#include <SPI.h>
File myFile;
int pinCS = 53; // Pin 10 on Arduino Uno
int total = 3;
void setup() {
    
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(pinCS, OUTPUT);
  
  // SD Card Initialization
  if (SD.begin())
  {
    Serial.println("SD card is ready to use.");
  } else
  {
    Serial.println("SD card initialization failed");
    return;
  }
  // Reading the file
  myFile = SD.open("test.txt", FILE_READ);
  if (myFile) {
    Serial.println("Read:");
    // Reading the whole file
    while (myFile.available()) {
      total += myFile.read();
      Serial.write(total);
   }
    myFile.close();
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("error opening test.txt");
  }
  
}
void loop() {
  // empty
}
```

What am I missing? Can you fix my code?

Comment: Which language, C++ or Java?  They have different methods for converting from text to integer.  For example, C++ has `std::istringstream` and `sprintf`, Java doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

[`read()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/FileRead) reads one character, so you have to convert the sequences of characters to integer value.

```
    while (myFile.available()) {
      total += myFile.read();
      Serial.write(total);
   }
```

should be

```
    int current = 0;
    while (myFile.available()) {
      int c = myFile.read();
      if ('0' <= c && c <= '9') {
        current = current * 10 + (c - '0');
      } else if (c == '\n') {
        total += current;
        current = 0;
        Serial.write(total);
      }
    }
```

Comment: it outputs `SD card is ready to use.
Read: squaresquare
` I can't add squares to this comment line

Comment: If I change `Serial.write` to `Serial.println` it gives me `SD card is ready to use. Read:4 6`. 4 is good but why it gives 6

Comment: How is the 4 good?  You said the file only contains a ‘1’.  What’s in the file now?

Comment: @Delta_G 3 is from `int total = 3;` and `3 + 1 = 4`.

Comment: The documentation for the Stream class says that both Serial and SD are based on it. If that is true, we should be able to use `myFile.parseInt()` to read an integer. You might have to read and ignore the CR/LF line endings if you want to read more.